# Adapting GSLB fortran code for use in R

Tags: r, fortran

I would like to adapt some Fortran 77 code so I can run programs and return results into R dataframes.  I understand from my net searching that there are some tools in R that will allow fortran code to be compiled and run from inside R - perhaps this involves writing a package?  I would appreciate if somebody could point me towards some beginner examples, books or tutorials on how I might go about starting to learn to do this. I have a reasonable understanding of Fortran 77 and running R, but am new to the idea of how to get the two languages to work together.

Comment: I had to install R from source on a linux box, and also had to install a fortran compiller in order for the config command to run.  I assume that means the R source contains fortran, possibly a version of lapack.  You could download the R source, and search for fortran code, and see how it is integrated with C/R.

Comment: You can also have a look at this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731807/r-fortran-call?rq=1)