# Fisher's Exact Variance Test for the Poisson Distribution

Tags: r, poisson, p-value

Following https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/240171/index-of-dispersion-how-to-test-its-significance

Do exist any R package that permits to compute the 'Fisher's Exact Variance Test for the Poisson Distribution' (http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2347079.pdf)?

If yes, how can I use it with my dataset in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/240171/index-of-dispersion-how-to-test-its-significance ?

Thanks

Comment: rseek.org shows no reference to this paper. It is a great resource for finding R things.

Comment: coded in fortran [here](http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/apstat/171). Can use this to make your own r code or call a [fortran routine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731807/r-fortran-call).

Comment: thanks. but I cannot understand fortran...does anyone can translate the fortran code into an R one?